# How can I set position of a GUI.Button in Inspector?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ConversationTrigger))]
public class ConversationTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private ConversationTrigger conversationtrigger;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        conversationtrigger = FindObjectOfType<ConversationTrigger>();
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0.1f,0.5f,0.1f,0.1f), "Add new item"))
        {
            conversationtrigger.conversations.Add(new Conversation());
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Save Conversations"))
        {
            conversationtrigger.SaveConversations();
        }

        if (GUILayout.Button("Load Conversations"))
        {
            Undo.RecordObject(conversationtrigger, "Loaded conversations from JSON");
            conversationtrigger.LoadConversations();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried this line :

```
if(GUI.Button(new Rect(0.1f,0.5f,0.1f,0.1f), "Add new item"))
```

But that make the button vanished like deleted.
If I'm using `GUILayout.Button` I will see the button but then I can't set the button position so I'm using `GUI.Button`.

I want to position the button `"Add new item"` before the `Canvas` field and always after the last conversation item, in this case the Locked Room. And if I will add a new item the button should  stay after the new added item and before the `Canvas` field.

I guess this values of the `Rect` are wrong making the button to be positioned out of the window.

This is a screenshot of the Inspector :

[image: Inspector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values for the `Rect` are `positionX`, `positionY`, `width` and `height` and for the Inspector they are in pixels. So

```
new Rect(0.1f,0.5f,0.1f,0.1f)
```

simply results in a really tiny little `0.1 x 0.1` pixel size button on the position `0.1 ,0.5` pixels of the current Inspector. Since you can't display something with size `0.1` pixels on the screen it is invisible.

---

Afaik you can use [`GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect.html) in order to get the `Rect` of the last control before the button and then place your button using that rect like e.g.

```
Rect lastRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect();

Rect buttonRect = new Rect(lastRect.x, lastRect.y + EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight, 100, 30);

if(GUI.Button(buttonRect, "AddNewItem")
    ...
```

to place the button I the next line under the last control and set it's size to `100px * 30px`.

---

I would however in general recommend to not mix `GUI` and `GUILayout` stuff. It is kind of the same like mixing `static` and `relative` in `css` ..

---

Depending on what exactly it is you want to change here you might rather want to use the optional `options` parameter to e.g. change the buttons height and width using

```
GUILayout.Button("AddNewItem", GUILayout.With(100), GUILayout.Height(30));
```

where the button starts in the X axis you could also change by temporarily change the [EditorGUI.indentLevel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI-indentLevel.html) e.g.

```
EditorGUI.indentLevel++
GUILayout.Button("AddNewItem", GUILayout.With(100), GUILayout.Height(30));
EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
```

For changing the position in Y direction you could either use [`EditorGUILayout.Space`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.Space.html)

```
EditorGUILayout.Space();
if(GUILayout.Button(...))
```

in order to have a small default space between the button and the control before or [`GUILayout.Space`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.Space.html) like e.g.

```
GUILayout.Space(30);
if(GUILayout.Button(...))
```

to set a fixed space in pixels.

---

**To your actual question**

If you really want to place a button in between the controls before you won't come around implementing the Editor for the entire inspector instead of using `DrawDefaultInspector` since it also means that you would have to make space for the button. Otherwise you might get multiple controls on top of each other.

I won't do that for you here. We can't even see the fields/types of your classes.

But since you are using a list/array there I (like I do quite often) once more strongly recommend to use the undocumented [`ReorderableList`](https://www.google.com/amp/s/xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2015/07/21/unity3d-using-reorderablelist-in-custom-editor/amp/) which not only is extremely fancy and allows you to rearrange items within the list by drag and drop but also implements `Add` and `Remove` buttons by default.

---

May I also ask why you do

```
conversationtrigger = FindObjectOfType<ConversationTrigger>();
```

This will fail as soon as you are dealing with an inactive GameObject, a disabled `ConversationTrigger`, a Prefab or simply multiple of those components in the scene.

In the Editor you already get the currently inspected component in [`target`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-target.html). All you have to do is to cast it like

```
conversationtrigger = (ConversationTrigger) target;
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: I was able to use the  ReorderableList in the link you have provided. Now I can drag the items and use the + and - to add/remove items. But how can I make that when clicking on the + it will add new empty item of my list type (Conversation) ? And how can I make that when clicking double click on one of the items or making a arrow that will collapse the items and show all the childs like in my screenshot in my question like Opening and others ?

Comment: I would be glad to help you on those points in a new question ;)